# For rails app, how to render all of pages inside a different folder to another html file in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two different folders in View folder, lets say them A and B.

In B folder, the content is generated by scaffold, so there is 5 html.erb files inside: _form.html.erb, edit.html.erb, index.html.erb, new.html.erb and show.html.erb.

What I need is only index.html.erb, edit.html.erb and _form.html.erb, which is because users are only allowed to edit the content and do nothing else.

In A folder, I have only 1 index.html.erb, and I want everything shows on this file. How to render the index and form file to it? I want users could see the content of index.html.erb and they can also click 'edit' to go to the form.html.erb. And the form should be in my A folder's index file, too..

Comment: @RajeshCO Sorry! my bad! I need edit.html.erb.

Comment: In folder A's index.html file you want folder's B index & form file ...right ?

Comment: @LHH yes,sir. I want the B index file's content appear on A's index.html file, maybe in a div, so the existed content in A's index.html file will not be affected.

Comment: and what about B's form file ?

Answer (score 2):

This information will help you: [Rendering an Action's Template from Another Controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller)

Comment: Thanks, but the instruction is too short to me.. I followed the steps (add render "B/index" to my A's controller), but got error: 

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #13):

10:     <th></th>
11:   </tr>
12: 
13: <% @plans.each do |plan| %>
14:   <tr>
15:     <td><%= plan.breakfast %></td>
16:     <td><%= plan.lunch %></td>

Comment: You should get @plans in your A controller, because it only renders a view without running action scripts

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know how to do that. Do you mean initialise @plans in my A controller?

Comment: Yes, as you've done it in B controller. I assume something like `@plans = Plan.all`

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you very much for your help, I think the problem is solved perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this in Folder A / index.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= render 'B/form' %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= render template: 'B/index' %>
</div>
```

Now these files will be rendered in folder's A index file

Comment: Thanks, but I got error:
Missing partial B/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.

Comment: updated my answer....you should render template for B'index (because it is not partial file)file..Please try that

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now it seems very close, but still have an error: 
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #13):

and this is some snippets of code in my B's index.html.erb:
10:     <th></th>
11:   </tr>
12: 
13: <% @plans.each do |plan| %>
14:   <tr>
15:     <td><%= plan.breakfast %></td>
16:     <td><%= plan.lunch %></td>


Do I need add or modify something in controller or model? I am quite now to rails so confused now.. thank you

Comment: OH, problem solved, I combined both Anton's and your answers, they are so helpful! 

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written, it seems you may benefit from [`prepend_view_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods/prepend_view_path):

```
#app/controllers/b_controller.rb
Class BController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :set_path
   private
   def set_path
      self.prepend_view_path "app/views/controller-a/"
   end
end
```